# Is it possible to show SimpleDialog internally?

Tags: mahapps.metro

I didn't really find any way to show `SimpleDialog` internally in `MetroWindow`. Is it possible?

**Note:** `SimpleDialog` has been renamed with `CustomDialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the [documentation for dialogs](http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html)? I also recommend to have a look at the [sample application](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/samples/MetroDemo/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L117-L128).

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at this myself. To show the dialog internally you use the ShowMetroDialogAsync Method on the MetroWindow:

From a user control:

```
((MetroWindow)Window.GetWindow(this)).ShowMetroDialogAsync(myMetroDialog);
```

And you can close it from inside the dialog using the MetroWindow.HideMetroDialogAsync:

```
parentWindow.HideMetroDialogAsync(this);
```